# Indirect Y indexed addressing mode in MOS 6502

Tags: assembly, 6502

I was looking at the addressing modes for the MOS 6502 instruction set from the [here](http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/6502_instruction_set.html).

The description of `indirect, Y-indexed` is a bit inconsistent with other sources.

It says

> OPC ($LL),Y        operand is effective address incremented by Y **with carry**; effective address is word at zeropage address

But other sources don't mention about the addition with carry bit. Like [here](https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/CPU_addressing_modes).

What is the right way of calculating the effective address?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When in doubt it's better to look at the official documentation.
There is a fascinating original datasheet from MOS [here](http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6501-6505_mpu_preliminary_aug_1975.pdf)
 <sup>also [[1](http://6502.org/documents/datasheets/mos/)]</sup> that reads

> INDIRECT INDEXED ADDRESSING - In indirect indexed addressing (referred to as `( Indirect) , Y`), the second byte of the instruction points to a memory location in page zero.
>   The contents of this memory location is added to the contents of the `Y` index register, the result being the low order eight bits of the *effective address*.
>   **The carry from this addition is added** to the contents of the next page zero
>   memory location, the result being the high order eight bits of the effective address.

So there the second addition is performed with carrying.
You can see this as a 16-bit addition between the 16-bit word pointed by `Immediate` (in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)) and the contents of the `Y` register zero extended to 16 bits.

For example, if the memory and `Y` are

```
All values in hex

Address    00  01  02  03  04 ...
Value      80  02  f3  00  03 ...

Y = 90
```

then `(0), Y` is

```
  low 8 bits:  80 + 90     = 10   (with carry = 1)
  high 8 bits: 02 + 00 + 1 = 03
```

giving an effective address of `0310`. Similarly `(3), Y` is

```
  low 8 bits:  00 + 90     = 90   (with carry = 0)
  high 8 bits: 03 + 00 + 0 = 03
```

that results in an effective address of value `0390`.

You can see that when considered as 16-bit quantities the word at 0 is `0280` and `Y` is `0090`, their addition is `0310` as expected.

The long description just encodes these facts: a) the 16-bit word pointed by `Indirect` is stored in little-endian b) `Y` is zero-extended c) the addition is a 16-bit one.

In C, it should look like this

```
uint16_t effective_addr(uint8_t indirect)
{
   //Take the INDIRECT immediate and make a pointer to a 16-bit LE word out of it
   //In C int-to-ptr is implementation define, we assume an identity map here
   uint16_t* page_zero_ptr = (uint16_t*)indirect;

   //The Y register is 8-bit, we consider it a 16-bit one instead
   //Assume y is of unsigned type 
   uint16_t  y_zero_ext = y;

   //Do a 16-bit addition, this is equivalent to two 8-bit additions with carry
   return *page_zero_ptr + y;
}
```

Comment: This clears the confusion. I thought the carry referred to the state of the carry bit before the instruction. Like how we refer in "add with carry". If I get it now clearly, it means Y is added to the address with carry? Also thank you for the C implementation and the link to the official document. I will refer to that hence forth. I am also editing in the question the 64 bit assembly equivalent. Could you confirm if that is correct?

Comment: @Ajay, It's usually better to post followup questions as new questions since major editings confuse future readers. The implementation doesn't look like correct to me, though I don't know how you want to use it. The indirect index address (IAM) mode takes an 8-bit immediate address and the implicit *Y* register, your inputs seem different. Besides that, you are making a *big-endian* word out of two bytes pointed by `rbx + \reg` and reading that (no addition?). That doesn't seem what IAM does. Further, this can be implemented with fewer and more idiomatic x86-64 instructions.

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question for the follow up. I will roll it back.

Comment: Nice explanation. The datasheet's descriptions is most likely a 1:1 description of how the hardware works with an 8-bit ALU. It is interesting if you intend to do a simulator with cycle-exact behaviour. For a simple understanding it is indeed overly complicated and might explain the confusion.

Comment: @Olaf it is not a 1:1 description of how the hardware works. What happens is: 1. fetch the opcode. 2. fetch the zp address. 3. fetch the byte at zp. 4. fetch the byte at zp+1. 5. Add Y to the low byte, concatenate with the high byte and fetch the byte at that address. 6. If there was a carry, increment the high byte of the address and fetch the byte again. This is why the instruction takes 5 cycles except when a page boundary is crossed when it taakes 6 cycles.

Comment: @Olaf it also means that `LDA (zpAddress),Y` may do two data reads, one from the page *before* the target address and one from the target address.

Comment: @JeremyP: I did not imply it shows how **all** units work and clock-wise. But how the 8 bit ALU processes the operation. It is a fine description for that part of the internal sequencer. For the memory fetcher, there are other details neded, of course. If you go into details as you tried, you have to add the decoder, pipelining/registering, etc.

Comment: @Olaf The instruction *does* have a varying cycle count. It will take 5 cycles if there is no carry and 6 cycles if there is a carry. Have a look at the data sheet supplied in the answer.

Comment: @JeremyP: Just checked: The `(IND),Y` addressing mode on the NMOS 6502 and 65C02 from WDC took a constant 5 clocks (`(IND,X)` has constant 6 clocks). I'm interested in how you got this information, though, always keen to see new facts. The absolute addressing modes (except `ABS,X`) took one extra clock for page-crossing, though. Maybe you confuse them?

Comment: @Olaf Timings changed for various later versions, but it is true of the original 6502 that you add an extra cycle to cross the page boundary for `(zp),Y`

Comment: @JeremyP: Hmm, just checked the preliminary DS: http://6502.org/documents/datasheets/mos/mos_6501-6505_mpu_preliminary_aug_1975.pdf page 7 and more recent ones (1985). Yes, that uses a global note about adding one cycle. But it does not state there is a double-read. It would be a bad idea, but not the first flaw int the design (ref. "illegal OP-codes"), but I can't find that mentioned.

Comment: @Olaf The reason it did it that way is because the 6502 did a read or write on *every clock cycle* in order to simplify the logic. So it had to do a read or write while it was doing the second part of the addition so it might as well read the address after just the low part of the addition so it could save a cycle if there was no carry. Here is an [article on 6502 timing and bus access](https://xania.org/201405/jsbeeb-getting-the-timings-right-cpu) which explains it very well. Note that the data is derived from Visual 6502, a transistor level simulation of a real 6502.

Comment: @JeremyP:Not sure about the name, I assume that the SMD board with LEDs everywhere? Read about that - fascination, although it doe not run at full clock. After I slpet over it, I have to admit it sounds reasonable; the CPU did not have a read-enable, but used the clock (PHI2 IIRC) to gate -OE on external devices. Thanks for the insight, I was a teenager when I designed my board without really knowing there is a datasheet (yet it worked)

Comment: For a 6502 variant to support "lda ($0),y" in five cycles when $00-$01 hold $FF FF and Y==1, it would need to be able to process a 7-wide carry chain in the time between sampling the fourth byte and generating the fifth address.  The 65C02 performs somewhat different dummy cycles from the 6502, and in case of a page-crossing load I think it does a dummy fetch fetches the byte following the instruction instead of fetching from an incorrect address, but there's not really enough time for it to generate the correct address in the page-crossing scenario without waiting a cycle.